# Color cell according to condition

Tags: javascript, eclipse, styles, birt

I have a table in which I have to set background color when the cell in header and cell in row appear as pair in a certain list in data source.
For example:
column : "AUD, USD"
row : "BRL, CZK"

in the cell of column AUD and row is BRL I check if exists in the list in datasource "AUD-BRL" and if so I need to color in a green

Now, I thought to do it in this way:
columns and rows will be in lists.
I go over both lists and then color in those indexes the cell.

So that I will have one function for whole table and not have to call from each cell to function (There are 1200 cells overall).
How can that be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from Fede MG is correct.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to add a highlighting rule to *all* cells in the table detail row. Unfortunately I think it is a bit cumbersome to achieve this in BIRT.

I assume that your table has e.g. bindings like COL_VALUE_1, ..., COL_VALUE_9 for the cell values and COL_TITLE_1, ..., COL_TITLE_9 for the column headers.

Furthermore I assume a bit of experience with using Javascript in BIRT.

The way I do this like this:

For each detail cell I create a `onCreate` event script with code like this:

```
highlightDetailCell(this, row, 1);
```

... where 1 is the column number. E.g. this is the code for the first column, for the second column i replace the 1 with 2 and so on. One can quickly do this with copy&paste.

Next I implement the logic in a function inside the `onInitialize` script of the report like this:

```
function highlightDetailCell(item, row, colnum) {
    var colTitle = row["COL_TITLE_" + colnum];
    var colValue = row["COL_VALUE_" + colnum];
    var highlight = use_your_logic_to_decide(colTitle, colValue);
    if (highlight) {
        item.get_Style().backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

This is the basic idea. If you want to add the script to many cells, it might be a lot of work to do this by hand. In fact it is possible to attach the call to the `highlightDetailCell` function with a script (of course, this is BIRT :-). You should read the documentation and just tinker with the [Design Engine API](https://www.eclipse.org/birt/documentation/integrating/deapi.php) (DE API for short).

**But be warned that writing and debugging such a script may be even more work than doing the donkey work of adding and editing a one-liner to 1200 cells!**

What I once did was basically this (in the `onFactory` event of the report item):

```
// This code is a simplified version that modifies just the first cell,
// However it should point you into the right direction.

// Some preparation
importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api);
var myconfig = reportContext.getReportRunnable().getReportEngine().getConfig();
var de = DataEngine.newDataEngine( myconfig, null );
var elementFactory = reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementFactory();

// Find the item you want to modify (in my case, a "Grid Item").
// Note that for tables, the structure is probably a bit different.
// E.G. tables have header, detail and footer rows, 
// while grids just have rows.
var containerGrid = reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("Layout MATRIX");

// Get the first row
var row0 = containerGrid.getRows().get(0);
// Do something with the first cell (:
var cell = row0.getCells().get(0).getContent();
cell.setStringProperty("paddingTop", "1pt");
cell.setStringProperty("paddingLeft", "1pt");
cell.setStringProperty("paddingRight", "1pt");
cell.setStringProperty("paddingBottom", "1pt");
cell.setStringProperty("borderBottomColor", "#000000");
cell.setStringProperty("borderBottomStyle", "solid");
cell.setStringProperty("borderBottomWidth", "thin");
cell.setStringProperty("borderTopColor", "#000000");
cell.setStringProperty("borderTopStyle", "solid");
cell.setStringProperty("borderTopWidth", "thin");
cell.setStringProperty("borderLeftColor", "#000000");
cell.setStringProperty("borderLeftStyle", "solid");
cell.setStringProperty("borderLeftWidth", "thin");
cell.setStringProperty("borderRightColor", "#000000");
cell.setStringProperty("borderRightStyle", "solid");
cell.setStringProperty("borderRightWidth", "thin");

// When you're finished:
de.shutdown( );
```

Things are more complicated if you have to handle merged cells.

You could even add content to the cell (I created a whole matrix dynamically this way).

The script does not exactly what you want (add the script to each cell), but I leave this as an exercise...

It is also helpful to save the dynamically modified report design for opening in the designer, to see the outcome:

```
reportContext.getDesignHandle().saveAs("c:/temp/modified_report.rptdesign");
```

HTH

Comment: There's no way of doing it via function for the whole table as a unit and looping over all cells with the condition?

Comment: I have to correct my comment regarding onPrepare (see comments to the other answer): What I had done was using the beforeFactory event of the report. Inside this I used the DE API to find the (in my case: ) grid item and modify it. I'll modify my answer a bit to give you a hint.

Comment: getting errors for method getrows:
TypeError: Cannot find function getRows in object org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.TableHandle@6b29fd6e. (/report/method[@name="beforeFactory"]#11)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.javascript.JavascriptEngine.evaluate(JavascriptEngine.java:295)
   at org.eclipse.birt.core.script.ScriptContext.evaluate(ScriptContext.java:159)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.evaluate(ExecutionContext.java:789)

Comment: I was using a grid, you are using a table. Probably the API is a slightliy different, maybe you should try getDetailRows().

Answer (score 2):

Go to the cell you want to format (applies also to elements like rows or columns), on the "Property Editor" go to "Highlights" and click "Add...". You'll get a dialog where you can enter a condition for the highlight and what styling to apply on the element if the condition is true.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L27Vz.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I don't want to set for each cell a condition since it will be endless work. and if i do for rows or columns, i don't know how to set it to a cell in this way.
can you elaborate more on how this can be done.

Comment: Then I'm afraid I didn't quite understand your problem... can you show an example of what you want to do?

Comment: I think that this conditional formatting won't help you then because the styling applies to the whole element... a possible alternative could be to write a script that applies styling to the cells you need, I've never done such a thing but I think it should be possible.